# Can autotools create multi-platform makefiles

Tags: 64-bit, makefile, 32-bit, autotools, multiplatform

I have a plugin project I've been developing for a few years where the plugin works with numerous combinations of [primary application version, 3rd party library version, 32-bit vs. 64-bit].  Is there a (clean) way to use autotools to create a single makefile that builds all versions of the plugin.

As far as I can tell from skimming through the autotools documentation, the closest approximation to what I'd like is to have N independent copies of the project, each with its own makefile.  This seems a little suboptimal for testing and development as (a) I'd need to continually propagate code changes across all the different copies and (b) there is a lot of wasted space in duplicating the project so many times.  Is there a better way?

**EDIT:**

I've been rolling my own solution for a while where I have a fancy makefile and some perl scripts to hunt down various 3rd party library versions, etc.  As such, I'm open to other non-autotools solutions.  For other build tools, I'd want them to be very easy for end users to install.  The tools also need to be smart enough to hunt down various 3rd party libraries and headers without a huge amount of trouble.  I'm mostly looking for a linux solution, but one that also works for Windows and/or the Mac would be a bonus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that. However, are you stuck with autotools? Are neither [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) nor [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) an option?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm doing some reading up on the both and seeing which is more likely to deal with some of the complexities of the build process like invoking special application-specific build wrappers instead of calling gcc directly.

Answer (score 6):

If your question is:

> Can I use the autotools on some machine A to create a single universal makefile that will work on all other machines?

then the answer is "No".  The autotools do not even make a pretense at trying to do that.  They are designed to contain portable code that will determine how to create a workable makefile on the target machine.

If your question is:

> Can I use the autotools to configure software that needs to run on different machines, with different versions of the primary software which my plugin works with, plus various 3rd party libraries, not to mention 32-bit vs 64-bit issues?

then the answer is "Yes".  The autotools are designed to be able to do that.  Further, they work on Unix, Linux, MacOS X, BSD.

I have a program, SQLCMD (which pre-dates the Microsoft program of the same name by a decade and more), which works with the IBM Informix databases.  It detects the version of the client software (called IBM Informix ESQL/C, part of the IBM Informix ClientSDK or CSDK) is installed, and whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.  It also detects which version of the software is installed, and adapts its functionality to what is available in the supporting product.  It supports versions that have been released over a period of about 17 years.  It is autoconfigured -- I had to write some autoconf macros for the Informix functionality, and for a couple of other gizmos (high resolution timing, presence of /dev/stdin etc).  But it is doable.

On the other hand, I don't try and release a single makefile that fits all customer machines and environments; there are just too many possibilities for that to be sensible.  But autotools takes care of the details for me (and my users).  All they do is:

```
./configure
```

That's easier than working out how to edit the makefile.  (Oh, for the first 10 years, the program was configured by hand.  It was hard for people to do, even though I had pretty good defaults set up.  That was why I moved to auto-configuration: it makes it much easier for people to install.)

---

Mr Fooz commented:

> I want something in between. Customers will use multiple versions and bitnesses of the same base application on the same machine in my case. I'm not worried about cross-compilation such as building Windows binaries on Linux.

Do you need a separate build of your plugin for the 32-bit and 64-bit versions?  (I'd assume yes - but you could surprise me.)  So you need to provide a mechanism for the user to say

```
./configure --use-tppkg=/opt/tp/pkg32-1.0.3
```

(where tppkg is a code for your third-party package, and the location is specifiable by the user.)   However, keep in mind usability: the fewer such options the user *has* to provide, the better; against that, do not hard code things that should be optional, such as install locations.  By all means look in default locations - that's good.  And default to the bittiness of the stuff you find.  Maybe if you find both 32-bit and 64-bit versions, then you should build both -- that would require careful construction, though.  You can always echo "Checking for TP-Package ..." and indicate what you found and where you found it.  Then the installer can change the options.  Make sure you document in '`./configure --help`' what the options are; this is standard autotools practice.

Do not do anything interactive though; the configure script should run, reporting what it does.  The Perl `Configure` script (note the capital letter - it is a wholly separate automatic configuration system) is one of the few intensively interactive configuration systems left (and that is probably mainly because of its heritage; if starting anew, it would most likely be non-interactive).  Such systems are more of a nuisance to configure than the non-interactive ones.

Cross-compilation is tough.  I've never needed to do it, thank goodness.

---

Mr Fooz also commented:

> Thanks for the extra comments. I'm looking for something like:

```
./configure --use-tppkg=/opt/tp/pkg32-1.0.3 --use-tppkg=/opt/tp/pkg64-1.1.2
```

> where it would create both the 32-bit and 64-bit targets in one makefile for the current platform.

Well, I'm sure it could be done; I'm not so sure that it is worth doing by comparison with two separate configuration runs with a complete rebuild in between.  You'd probably want to use:

```
./configure --use-tppkg32=/opt/tp/pkg32-1.0.3 --use-tppkg64=/opt/tp/pkg64-1.1.2
```

This indicates the two separate directories.  You'd have to decide how you're going to do the build, but presumably you'd have two sub-directories, such as '`obj-32`' and '`obj-64`' for storing the separate sets of object files.  You'd also arrange your makefile along the lines of:

```
FLAGS_32 = ...32-bit compiler options...
FLAGS_64 = ...64-bit compiler options...

TPPKG32DIR = @TPPKG32DIR@
TPPKG64DIR = @TPPKG64DIR@

OBJ32DIR = obj-32
OBJ64DIR = obj-64

BUILD_32 = @BUILD_32@
BUILD_64 = @BUILD_64@

TPPKGDIR =
OBJDIR   =
FLAGS    =

all:    ${BUILD_32} ${BUILD_64}

build_32:
    ${MAKE} TPPKGDIR=${TPPKG32DIR} OBJDIR=${OBJ32DIR} FLAGS=${FLAGS_32} build

build_64:
    ${MAKE} TPPKGDIR=${TPPKG64DIR} OBJDIR=${OBJ64DIR} FLAGS=${FLAGS_64} build

build:  ${OBJDIR}/plugin.so
```

This assumes that the plugin would be a shared object.   The idea here is that the autotool would detect the 32-bit or 64-bit installs for the Third Party Package, and then make substitutions.  The BUILD_32 macro would be set to build_32 if the 32-bit package was required and left empty otherwise; the BUILD_64 macro would be handled similarly.

When the user runs '`make all`', it will build the build_32 target first and the build_64 target next.  To build the build_32 target, it will re-run `make` and configure the flags for a 32-bit build.  Similarly, to build the build_64 target, it will re-run `make` and configure the flags for a 64-bit build.  It is important that all the flags affected by 32-bit vs 64-bit builds are set on the recursive invocation of `make`, and that the rules for building objects and libraries are written carefully - for example, the rule for compiling source to object must be careful to place the object file in the correct object directory - using GCC, for example, you would specify (in a `.c.o` rule):

```
${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o ${OBJDIR}/$*.o -c $*.c
```

The macro CFLAGS would include the ${FLAGS} value which deals with the bits (for example, `FLAGS_32 = -m32` and FLAGS_64 = -m64`, and so when building the 32-bit version,`FLAGS = -m32`would be included in the`CFLAGS` macro.

The residual issues in the autotools is working out how to determine the 32-bit and 64-bit flags.  If the worst comes to the worst, you'll have to write macros for that yourself.  However, I'd expect (without having researched it) that you can do it using standard facilities from the autotools suite.

Unless you create yourself a carefully (even ruthlessly) symmetric makefile, it won't work reliably.

Comment: I want something in between.  Customers will use multiple versions and bitnesses of the same base application on the same machine in my case.  I'm not worried about cross-compilation such as building Windows binaries on Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments.  I'm looking for something like "./configure --use-tppkg=/opt/tp/pkg32-1.0.3 --use-tppkg=/opt/tp/pkg64-1.1.2", where it would create both the 32-bit and 64-bit targets in one makefile for the current platform.

Answer (score 1):

We tried it and it doesn't work! So we use now [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

Some articles to this topic: [1](http://freshmeat.net/articles/view/1702/) and [2](http://freshmeat.net/articles/view/2799/)

**Edit:**
Some small example why I love SCons:

```
env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0')
```

With this line of code you add GLib to the compile environment (*env*). And don't forget the [User Guide](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.1.0/HTML/scons-user/book1.html) which just great to learn SCons (you really don't have to know Python!). For the end user you could try SCons with [PyInstaller](http://pyinstaller.python-hosting.com/wiki) or something like that.

And in comparison to `make`, you use Python, so a complete programming language! With this in mind you can do just everything (more or less).

Comment: I'll take a look at scons.  I hadn't heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered to use a single project with multiple build directories?
if your automake project is implemented in a proper way (i.e.: NOT like gcc)

the following is possible:

```
mkdir build1 build2 build3
cd build1
../configure $(YOUR_OPTIONS)
cd build2
../configure $(YOUR_OPTIONS2)
[...]
```

you are able to pass different configuration parameters like include directories and compilers (cross compilers i.e.).

you can then even run this in a single make call by running

```
make -C build1 -C build2 -C build3
```